# find closest link of selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="action">
    <input type="text" id="StudentName" />
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <input type="text" id="item1" />
    <input type="text" id="item2" />
    <a href="#">yahoo</a>
    <input type="text" id="item3" />
    <a href="#">gmail</a>
    <input type="text" id="item4" />
    <a href="#">facebook</a>
</div>
```

I want to find closest link `<a></a>` for my selector. I tried this:

```
$("#StudentName").closest('a')
```

What is the right way?

Comment: this will give you first <a> with yahoo, so what you want to do?

Comment: It's not done, `closest()` travels DOM up not searching in siblings

Comment: no, you want `$('#StudentName').parent().find('a:first')`

Comment: Closest in terms of... what? Given your example, which element do you actually want to find?

Comment: i want to change name yahoo in  link , like <a>yahoo.com</a> to <a>abc.com</a>

Comment: this worked for me . $('#StudentName').parent().find('a:first')

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$("#StudentName").siblings('a:first').html('yahooo');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('#StudentName').parent().find('a:first')` as suggested by @georg. This will find first `a` which is a child of the parent element.
You can also use `$('#StudentName').siblings('a:first')` which will find first a in the same DOM level.

Answer (score 0):

> i want to change name yahoo in link , like yahoo.com to abc.com

uses `siblings` and then `filter` on the text, before calling `text` to change.

```js
$('#StudentName').siblings('a').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == 'yahoo';
}).text('abc.com')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="action">
  <input type="text" id="StudentName" />
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <input type="text" id="item1" />
  <input type="text" id="item2" />
  <a href="#">yahoo</a>
  <input type="text" id="item3" />
  <a href="#">gmail</a>
  <input type="text" id="item4" />
  <a href="#">facebook</a>
</div>
```